# Can we execute Cucumber Test in single command based on condition of tags if @smoke result is pass then only execute @Regression

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber-java

I have a situation/ requirement to create a single run command or a script file such that it will execute @Smoke tag test first if the result is pass then execute @Regression tag else abort the execution.

We have BDD (cucumber + Selenium + Java) with Maven project. Is this possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using [Cucumber with JUnit 5](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/cucumber-junit-platform-engine), then you can use the [JUnit Platform Launcher API](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api) to programmatically run your tests.

```java
public class RunCucumber {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = request()
              .selectors(
                      selectDirectory("path/to/features")
              )
              .filters(
                      includeTags("Smoke"),
              )
              .build();

      Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create();
      SummaryGeneratingListener listener = new SummaryGeneratingListener();
      launcher.registerTestExecutionListeners(listener);
      launcher.execute(request);

      TestExecutionSummary summary = listener.getSummary();
      // Do something with summary

      // Repeat for regression tests if needed.
   }

}
```